# SAS intck function return wrong

Tags: function, date, sas

Couldn't figure out why the intck function return wrong days. Any clue?
Thanks!

```
data b;    
   WeddingDay='14FEB2000'd;    
   Today='28MAR2000'd;    
   daysMarried=INTCK('day',WeddingDay,today());
   format WeddingDay Today date9.;
run;

proc print data=b; run;
```

> 1     14FEB2000    28MAR2000      5659

Comment: You're using the today function instead of your own today variable.

Comment: @sasfrog, Thank you for wisely pointing that out!

Comment: Just make sure you don't get your wedding date wrong ;)

Comment: hehe...SAS is not needed to count wedding anniversary  :)

Answer (score 0):

Use INTCK function to calculate the number of days between two dates.

```
data want;
   WeddingDay = '14FEB2000'd;
   Today = '28MAR2000'd;
   daysMarried = INTCK('day',WeddingDay,today);
   format WeddingDay Today date9.;
run;
```